# Adding an arrow on the right side of the badge in list group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add an arrow icon (from font-awsome) in a list group. The problem is it shows up on the left side of the badge instead of the right. How can I fix it?

**Example:**
[image]

**My HTML (using Bootstrap):**

```
   <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Friends
            <span class="badge">0</span>
            <span class="icon-angle-right pull-right"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Items
            <span class="badge">0</span> 
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the `.badge` is floated right, so you need to change the order of the elements:

```
<li class="list-group-item">Friends
    <span class="icon-angle-right pull-right"></span>
    <span class="badge">0</span>
</li>
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/sUqGw/)**